# How can I flip an imported object from a module in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, import, flip

I'm programming a Mario running animation and I'm importing into my animation from outside modules like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ObjectMario import Mario1, Mario2, Mario3
from ObjectMarioBlocks import Ground, Platform, Question1, Question2, Coin
import winsound
import os
```

What I want to do is flip the image to make him able to run backwards. I was wondering if there is some way to accomplish this with some command that I can flip across the "yaxis".

Each imported object is like the following:
named ObjectMarioBlocks

from Tkinter import *

class Ground:

```
# class attributes
objectName = "MarioGround"   # Title for this object
objectNum = 0                         # Number of instances created

#######################################################################
#  __init__ constructor                                               #
#                                                                     #
#  Initializes all attributes to given parameters.                    #
#  Calcualtes the tag attribute                                       #
#  Increments the count class attribute.                              #
#######################################################################
def __init__ (self, canvas, left=0,top=0,width=100,height=100):
    # attributes from parameters
    self.c = canvas
    self.left = left
    self.top = top
    self.width = width

    # calculated attributes
    self.tag = Ground.objectName + str(Ground.objectNum)
    Ground.objectNum += 1
    self.right = self.left + self.width
    self.bottom = self.top + self.width
    self.center = (self.left + self.right) / 2.0
    self.middle = (self.top + self.bottom) / 2.0

#######################################################################
#  draw method                                                        #
#                                                                     #
#  Draws the face according to the attributes, including position,    #
#  size, and colors.                                                  #
#######################################################################
def draw(self):
    # create X-coordinate grid
    xspaces = 30  # number of coordinates in the guide list
    gridwidth = 1.0 * self.width / xspaces
    x = []
    for i in range(xspaces+1):
        x.append(self.left + i*gridwidth)

    # create Y-coordinate grid
    yspaces = 20  # number of coordinates in the guide list
    gridheight = 1.0 * self.width / yspaces
    y = []
    for i in range(yspaces+1):
        y.append(self.top + i*gridheight)

    # definfleftsquare
    leftsquare  = (  (x[0],y[0]) , (x[20],y[20])  )
    # definetopsquare
    topsquare  = (  (x[20],y[0]) , (x[30],y[10])  )
    # definebottomsquare
    bottomsquare  = (  (x[20],y[10]) , (x[30],y[20])  )

    # draw leftsquare
    self.c.create_rectangle(leftsquare, fill="Orangered2", width=5)
    # draw topsquare
    self.c.create_rectangle(topsquare, fill="Orangered2", width=5)
    # draw bottomsquare
    self.c.create_rectangle(bottomsquare, fill="Orangered2", width=5)

    # update canvas, if running an animation
    self.c.update()
```

the animation imports the classes then runs them in the animation

Comment: You have three `Mario1`, `Mario2`, and `Mario3`; is one of those the thing you want to flip? If so, which one? More importantly, what types of things are those, and how are you drawing them? Can you give us a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows everything else relevant working, and shows where you're stuck?

Comment: You're going to have to tell us more, such as what an `ObjectMario` is. Is it an image? OpenGL drawing instructions? XML?